# what is the power of the total battery?

Tags: batteries

if 4 batteries of 12v/7.2ah batteries are connected in series then what is the total power? I know the voltage is 12v each so total voltage is 48v but current depends on load how do I calculate its power?

Comment: Think about the unit of each known physical quantity and the unit of the physical quantity of what you are looking for. Do you have any missing unknowns? Yes. Can the question be answered? No.

Answer (score 4):

You do not know and cannot know "the power". As you say, it depends on the load current.

What you can do is calculate the energy available. Since the batteries are rated for 7.2 Ah, they will last (for instance) for 7.2 hours at a current of 1 amp. In this case the power would be 48 watts for 7.2 hours, or 345.6 Whr. Note that the total energy (using this approach) is independent of current. If you halve the current the duration is doubled, so you get half the current, and half the power, for twice the time. It all cancels out.

Answer (score 2):

With no load there is no current and zero power. If you want to calculate the power taken by a load you need to know the value of the load. The power of a battery is a nonsensical term unless loaded.

Comment: hey, andy, but how normal batteries have given the specification of 12v/7.2ah ????

Comment: Voltage by current by time is *energy*, not power.

Comment: @pankajprasad "7.2 Ah" means it can supply 7.2 amps for 1 hour or 1 amp for 7.2 hours. It's not a definitive value of current - it is ampere-hours and not watts or joules BUT it is more related to joules (i.e. the amount of energy the fully charged battery can store but a battery data sheet would be needed to convert that to joules).

Comment: You could convert to joules by assuming that the battery terminal voltage remains constant whilst being discharged but, that would lead to an over-estimate of energy available and that is not recommended. Some battery specifications may assume that the depletion of the cell (i.e. 7.2 amps for 1 hour) means that the battery terminal voltage has dropped as low as 75% and this of course alters the power delivered to the load and the toal energy delivered. A data sheet is required to make a decent estimate.

Comment: But is possible to define a maximum load current of the battery. The voltage and current for the maximum load power may be different.

Comment: @Uwe are you addressing this comment to me or someone else?

Answer (score 1):

Total energy of 1 battery is 12V * 7.2Ah = 86.4 watt hours.

So 4 batteries * 86.4 watt hours = 345.6 watt hours.

The batteries themselves dictate most of the constraints.

Their internal resistance will reduce the voltage provided if the load resistance is too low (too much current provided.)

The rating for amp hours still remains at 7.2Ah when connecting the batteries in series.

Answer (score 1):

Power and Energy are two different measures.
The Power is the amount of energy in a given time, depends on the load.

Thats why lightbulbs, for example are rated in watts.

Power(watts) = Current(amps) x Volts 
P=IV.

Energy is the total work that you can achieve, and is power multiplied by time.

Energy (watt hours) is Power(watts) x Time (hours).

OK, I'm being simple - the SI unit for power is actually Joules, where one Joule = 1 watt for 1 second, but for this case, we will use watt-hours for the simple reason that it is more meaningful in real life in this case.

In this case, the battery pack is 48V and 7.2Ah.
So it will nominally deliver 7.2 amps into a load for 1 hour.
So, in watt-hours, the battery will deliver 7.2 x 48 = 345.6 watt hours.

So, it will run a 1 watt bulb for 345 hours, or a 100 watt bulb for 3.45 hours etc,.

To get from resistance to current, use Ohms law.
current (I) = Voltage/Resistance.

At 48 volts, a 100 ohm load will draw 0.48amps, and use power at the rate of:-
48 (volts) x 0.48 (amps) = 23.04 watts.

Does this make sense?

Be aware that the battery rating of 7.2ah is the absolute maximum Amp Hours that the battery can store.

Very few batteries can actually deliver 100% of their rated charge without suffering some ill effects - it's good practice to not fully discharge batteries.

Also, be careful when handling these - a short across the terminals will produce a very large overload...